# find and replace in a photo (multi image )

Tags: image, resize, photoshop, watermark, photos

I am copying from a site which puts its address in right down corner of the images .
But i want to crop or delete the address and replace it with my own watermark.
But i want to crop or delete the address and replace it with my own watermark.
i want to do this for bulk of images .

Is there any way that i can do this with Multiple images.

For example 20 image .

I'm already can do re size bulk images and water mark multiple images 

But cropping some special place in every images is my question.

certain position in a photo should be deleted and replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros, and can be installed on OS X using `homebrew` and can also be downloaded for Windows from [here](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Say you have an original image like this:

[image]

and you have a watermark saved in a file called `watermark.png` you can do this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity southeast watermark.png -composite result.jpg
```

which wil give you this:

[image]

As regards batching the commands, you don't say what OS you are using, but if it is OSX, you would do something like this in Terminal:

```
mkdir watermarked
for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" -gravity southeast watermark.png -composite watermarked/"$f"; done
```

If you are on Windows, you will need to use the mad Windows FOR loop syntax, which is *something* like

```
md watermarked
FOR %A IN (*.jpg) DO convert %A -gravity southeast watermark.png -composite watermarked/%A
```

Answer (score 1):

@Greatone, you will have to use the ACTIONS feature of PS to accomplish this. However, to do your specific task, you will need all the images to have a common dimension, either they should all have the same height or the same width. Are your images like that?

Comment: yes , i got my answer ... actions is the key 
thanx all

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend photoshop because you can create actions using photoshop and for that you only need to do the task just once very neatly and precisely. So just record action while performing the task once, assign shortcut and complete your task easily and in no time.